# How to detect Raspberry Pi board model?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am now working with several Raspberry Pi boards.
I have Pi Zero W, 3B+ and 4B.

I am going to run the same program across all those models.
To do so, I need to detect Raspberry board model from Python code.
Like this,

```py
def detect_board():
    '''
    return string representing board type, one of the following
        4B
        3B+
        3B
        ...
        Zero W
        Zero
    '''
```

How can I get the board model name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61699/which-model-raspberry-pi-i-am-running

Comment: It works, Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to comment from @Ani, I created the detection function like this,

```py
def detect_model() -> str:
    with open('/proc/device-tree/model') as f:
        model = f.read()
    return model
```